# Sign flutter apk with deployment and upload certificate

Tags: android, flutter

I have released an application (written in Kotlin) about 1 year ago and distributed it through the play store with Google Play App Signing enabled. I have now rewritten the application in flutter. Uploading and deploying the apk requires that it is signed with the previously used upload and deployment certificates. How do I do that?

Comment: Do you have the .jks keystore file that you use the sign previous android app? you should use it. [Guide](https://flutter.io/android-release/)

Comment: Still, had the key and used it to sign the apk. Upload gave no error. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

import the der certificate and sign again the app

```
keytool -importcert -file <google-play-console-certificate>.der -keystore <your-keystore-name>.jks
```

with the configuration already in place, you should be able to rebuild the app and distribute it

Comment: I did the same but unfortunately it didn't work because this .der file is public file and it does not work.
``` trusted certificate entries are not password-protected```